# Weird semi-black screen with Debian install

Tags: debian, installation

I'm trying to install Debian 9.5 (Stable) from a live USB. I got to the installation menu, but once I continue to select "Graphical Install" or just plain "Install", I'm presented with a partially black screen that has on top a chain of more than 20 small size "language selection" boxes (I presume, I can't really tell. It's pixel size small.)

I'm trying to install this on a laptop.

Specs:

- Intel i7-8750H
- gtx 1070
- 2x PCIe-NVMe (one clean, one with Windows 10 Pro)

Other observations:

- I tried installing Ubuntu (latest version) and everything seemed fine, even when trying it out without installation.
- I have disabled Discrete Graphics from BIOS.
- UEFI is enabled.
- Disabled secure boot.
- I'm a newbie to GNU/linux.

Here's a link that depicts the problem (sorry, bad quality photo ahead):

[image]

Comment: Debian is very serious about open source and doesn't bundle proprietary stuff with its standard distro.  You may be running into driver issues.  Download the "non-free" DVD (it's no-cost, the non-free refers to not being open source).  You may actually be able to select including it at the time you download the ISO, which will simplify installation.  Ubuntu bundles this kind of stuff with the distro so that it works out of the box.

Comment: From OP (posted in answers that were deleted): Tried Debian 9.5 live-KDE non-free version, but the same problem persists.  I was, however, able to install it as a VM (using VirtualBox) in Windows 10.

Comment: It looks like you have created multiple accounts, which will interfere with your ability to edit your posts,  comment within your thread, and accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by downloading the testing version of Debian. The previous versions simply struggled with new hardware.I would advice every user that employs a more recent setup to do the same. After that I just appended “nomodeset” followed by “nosplash” when loading the kernel. Thanks again for the help. 
J.